# VBA app throwing error in Windows 7 , office 2010 but not in Win XP

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010

I have an app in VBA consisting of many reports, queries, forms and tables. This `.mdb` file is linked to another `.mdb` file (the actual database for the app). This app was originally developed in Windows XP. But I have to move this app to run from a machine which has Windows 7. Now when I run a particular report in win 7 machine it throws an error.

> The expression On Deactivate you entered as the event property setting produced the following error : A problem occurred while  application was communicating with the OLE server or Active X component

When I comment out the Deactivate event from that particular report, the error is no more. But the interesting point is, when I use the same `.mdb` file to run from a XP machine, it works just fine.

I am very much confused. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What's happening in the Deactivate event?

Comment: The same happening in all the other reports. I am just making the toolbar visible in the Deactivate event. Another interesting Fact is that, the compiler is not reading through any other events. I tried giving messg boxes in the Activate event , Load event. But it refuses to read those events. No messg box is being popped up.

Comment: I'm assuming it's the same version of Access (2010)? Also, can you post some code?

Comment: tried run it in elevated mode? when things work in XP but not Vista or later, it sounds like UAC blocked it in background.

Comment: @@Spitz:The .mdb file was originaly built in 2003 version. But Office 2010 is installed in the Win 7 version.

Comment: @@Patrick: How to run in elevated mode?

Comment: Sorry Gentlemen , Can not post any code because of some compliance issues of the Organization I work for. I am extremely sorry. Thanks for understanding.

Comment: @@Patrick: I have the admin access. Still do I need to run it on the elevated mode?

Comment: I have solved it. Thanks all for your valuable feed back.I created a new report and one by one I copied the controls from the previous report, till the moment I got the error. The moment I got the error, I discarded that very control and re created that very control again. After I copied the other controls and created the  erroneous control once again, the error was gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new report and, one by one, copy the controls from the previous report till the moment you get the error. The moment you got the error,  discard that very control and recreate that very control again in the new report. After that copy the other remaining controls.

The idea is to pinpoint the control or controls which are causing the pain and then to discard those controls and recreate them again.